# What are Unity RectTransform anchors for, and how do they affect the gameObject?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, anchorpoint

I was just curious if anybody here knows a bit about Unity RectTransform Anchors for? Basically, why have them at all? They just confused me. The other part of the question is how they affect the gameObject, this would really help me out with my UI development.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor is useful for ensuring that your UI will maintain its position and size relative to the screen size. Let us say you have a UI design for a 16:9 device, if you play on a device with 4:3 resolution, that UI will not adjust and will probably take up most of the screen. With anchoring, how the UI will look in a 16:9 will adjust to a 4:3 device like how far will the sides be from the screen border, or how a button should always be at the top-right most part of the UI.

Comment: So what do the four different anchor points do? What you described could be done with just one Vector2 object, but unity gives four corners (defined by xMin, xMax, yMin and yMax)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `Anchors`?

if perhaps you mean `RectTransform.anchoredPosition`, that is simply the pivot point of your UI object, relative to the anchor reference point.

if you are talking about the anchor reference points, they tell the UI object where to render and how to treat movements.

Think about it this way: you anchor something to the bottom of a window, and it will move up as you re-size the bottom of the window upward. if you anchor to the right of the window, the object will move left if you re-scale the right hand side of the window left.

Comment: No, you're talking about the pivot point, a Vector2 object. The OP is asking about anchor points, there are 4 anchor points, defined by four floats (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax).